# Applescript freezes when extracting email from mail

Tags: email, applescript

I'm running an applescript to extract all the email adress from all the messages in my boss's inbox and it freezes on his computer and works fine on mine.

my computer is running Snow leopard with mail 4.6 and his is running Lion with mail 5.3 if that makes any difference.

Also my inbox only has around 400 mails since i don't usually use mail and only got those messages to test the script and his has over 60 000.

The script ran through my email in around 20 seconds and on his took 2 minutes to do 40 then froze.

I was wondering if there was anything wrong with the code that could cause it to freeze in his higher version or due to the increase in email present.

On another note i know that writing them all one by one is probably counter-productive because the script i adapted this from was sorting the adresses and removing duplicates before writing them to the file but i thought that due to the large number of mails that it would speed the process and use less memory to just write them. PLus the counters helps to know where the script is at.

here is the code :

```
tell application "Finder" to set ptd to path to documents folder as string
    set theFile to ptd & "extracted3.txt"
    set theFileID to open for access theFile with write permission

set counter to 0

tell application "Mail"
    set selectionMessage to selection -- just select the first message in the folder
    set thisMessage to item 1 of selectionMessage
    set theseMessages to (every message in (mailbox of thisMessage))
    repeat with eachMessage in theseMessages
        try
            set counter to counter + 1
            set theFrom to (extract address from sender of eachMessage)
            set theFromName to (extract name from sender of eachMessage)
            set theFromTemp to theFrom & "," & theFromName & "," & counter
            write theFromTemp & return to theFileID as «class utf8»
            if (address of to recipient) of eachMessage is not {} then
                repeat with i from 1 to count of to recipient of eachMessage
                    set theTo to (address of to recipient i) of eachMessage as string
                    set theToName to (name of to recipient i) of eachMessage as string
                    set theToTemp to theTo & "," & theToName & "," & counter
                    write theToTemp & return to theFileID as «class utf8»
                end repeat
            end if
            if (address of cc recipient) of eachMessage is not {} then
                repeat with i from 1 to count of cc recipient of eachMessage
                    set theCC to (address of cc recipient i) of eachMessage as string
                    set theCCName to (name of cc recipient i) of eachMessage as string
                    set theCCTemp to theCC & "," & theCCName & "," & counter
                    write theCCTemp & return to theFileID as «class utf8»
                end repeat
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

close access theFileID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT***: after further thought, I removed the first script I posted. My thought is the problem you are seeing is because you are getting 60,000+ emails at once in this line...

```
set theseMessages to (every message in (mailbox of thisMessage))
```

So the idea is to just get a bunch at a time. I use the variable writeEveryXMessages to specify that you should get 500 messages at a time, and on each loop we get the next 500 until finished.

NOTE: I modified your code to be a little more efficient and fixed a few possible bugs, for example the write command is no longer in the Mail tell block of code. Also it now writes those 500 messages to file at one time. This script works on Mountain Lion and Mail v6.2. It should work for you too.

I hope this fixes your problem! Good luck.

```
set theFile to (path to documents folder as text) & "extracted3.txt"
set writeEveryXMessages to 500
set counter to 1

try
    set theFileID to open for access file theFile with write permission

    tell application "Mail"
        set selectedMessage to item 1 of (get selection)
        set theMailbox to mailbox of selectedMessage
        set messageCount to count of messages in theMailbox
    end tell

    repeat
        set endCount to counter + writeEveryXMessages
        if endCount is greater than messageCount then set endCount to messageCount
        set theString to ""

        tell application "Mail"
            set theseMessages to messages counter thru endCount of theMailbox
        end tell

        repeat with eachMessage in theseMessages
            set theFromTemp to ""
            set theToTemp to ""
            set theCCTemp to ""

            try
                tell application "Mail"
                    tell eachMessage
                        set theSender to sender
                        set toRecipients to to recipients
                        set ccRecipients to cc recipients
                    end tell

                    set theFrom to extract address from theSender
                    set theFromName to extract name from theSender
                    set theFromTemp to "From: " & theFrom & "," & theFromName & "," & counter & return

                    if toRecipients is not {} then
                        repeat with toRecipient in toRecipients
                            try
                                set theTo to address of toRecipient
                                set theToName to name of toRecipient
                                set theToTemp to theToTemp & "  To: " & theTo & "," & theToName & "," & counter & return
                            end try
                        end repeat
                    end if

                    if ccRecipients is not {} then
                        repeat with ccRecipient in ccRecipients
                            try
                                set theCC to address of ccRecipient
                                set theCCName to name of ccRecipient
                                set theCCTemp to theCCTemp & "  CC: " & theCC & "," & theCCName & "," & counter & return
                            end try
                        end repeat
                    end if
                end tell

                set theString to theString & theFromTemp & theToTemp & theCCTemp & return
            end try

            set counter to counter + 1
        end repeat

        write theString to theFileID as «class utf8»
        if counter is greater than or equal to messageCount then
            set theString to ""
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    close access theFileID
on error theError
    log theError
    try
        close access file theFile
    end try
end try
```

Comment: thank you very much it resolved my problem you are a real life saver

Comment: @regulus6633 Can you tell me why you "tell application "Mail"
                    tell eachMessage…" syntax, please? Does this create a property with each message object in the mail app object?

Comment: You have to look in Mail's applescript dictionary to understand when you need to ask for information from the mail application itself or when you need to get information from a message. The dictionary shows the properties that you can query and who you need to ask. In AppleScript Editor under the File menu choose "open dictionary" and select the Mail application. Look through that.